Print vector name with vector value iteratively in R
I'm sure there's already a solution to this question on here, but for the life of me, I can't figure out the right way to search for it, so here goes.
Say I've got a named vector
vector <- c(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3)
How can I get the following output printed as a string, say using paste
"a=1; b=2; c=3"


You can use paste like so:
paste(names(vector), "=", vector, collapse = "; ")
#[1] "a = 1; b = 2; c = 3"

Or use paste0 if you don't want the space:
paste0(names(vector), "=", vector, collapse = "; ")
#[1] "a=1; b=2; c=3"


Ah, so bloody obvious! Thanks!

You can use deparse + sub + chartr like below (but not as simple or efficient as paste0)
> chartr(",", ";", sub("c\\((.*)\\)", "\\1", deparse(vector)))
[1] "a = 1; b = 2; c = 3"

